# Docusaurus single level sidebar

Tags: docusaurus

I'm building a website with [Docusaurus V2](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/introduction).

Here is my `sidebars.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  docs: {
    '10 Studio': ['introduction'],
    'Getting Started': ['trySamples', 'installation'],
    'Formula Editor': ['formulaEditor'],
    'Spreadsheet Verificator': ['spreadsheetVerificator'],
    'Bottleneck Detector': ['bottleneckDetector'],
    'Spreadsheet Optimizer': ['spreadsheetOptimizer'],
    'Contact & Community': ['contactAndCommunity'],
  },
};
```

The result is as follows. As we can see, for `Spreadsheet Verificator`, `Bottleneck Detector`, etc., a second level is not necessary. Does anyone know how we could make them only one level?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still working on this. A more flexible format will be available in future.

Comment: Hello, do you have any idea about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937221/docusaurus-fails-with-ie-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-assign? We are blocked by this. It seems that my developer has to modify the code of Docusaurus. Could you give some hint?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following for a single level:

```json
{ 
  type: 'ref'
  id: 'spreadsheetVerificator'
}
```