# Docusaurus fails with IE: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, cross-browser, docusaurus, core-js

We are making a V2 Docusaurus website: https://www.10studio.tech.

We have just realized that it does not work well in IE, for instance, IE11. The error message is: `Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'`.

[image]

There are some packages to provide with IE compatibility such as `core-js`, but we don't know how to properly add it to Docusaurus v2.

Does anyone know how to amend this?

Comment: How are you bundling this app? Did you use `create-react-app` or are you using a custom `Webpack` config/etc..?

Comment: Docusaurus uses `Webpack`, probably with this one: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/master/packages/docusaurus/src/webpack/client.ts

Comment: What do you mean probably? It's important to know how you're bundling this app. At any rate, you need polyfills to make this work. See the following link for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56439822/10431732

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that object doesn't have an `assign` `function`. `assign` is a `function` which apparently is not supported in the browser you are speaking about, so you need to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill) it. A good example is:

```
if (!Object.assign) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object, 'assign', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function(target) {
      'use strict';
      if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert first argument to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);
      for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[i];
        if (nextSource === undefined || nextSource === null) {
          continue;
        }
        nextSource = Object(nextSource);

        var keysArray = Object.keys(Object(nextSource));
        for (var nextIndex = 0, len = keysArray.length; nextIndex < len; nextIndex++) {
          var nextKey = keysArray[nextIndex];
          var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nextSource, nextKey);
          if (desc !== undefined && desc.enumerable) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    }
  });
}
```

which can be found here: https://gist.github.com/spiralx/68cf40d7010d829340cb

However, even though this will fix the problem you were complaining about, it is highly probable that other problems will occur as well. You might need to polyfill some other stuff as well, you might want to take a look into [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/) in order to achieve this.